# What exactly is swift_unexpectedError at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode12

I am getting assertionFailure and swift_unexpectedError. Here is my code where it shows the crash:

```
if let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio) {
    let audioIn = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice) /* Line of crash */
    if captureSession.canAddInput(audioIn) {
        captureSession.addInput(audioIn)
    }
}
```

This happened only after I built the code with Xcode 12 and updated the app. No crash happened before in the same line of code when I built the code with Xcode 11.

```
  Crashed: com.capturePipeline.sessionQueue
 0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1ae506730 _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 492
 1  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1ae568d98 swift_unexpectedError + 436
 2  MyApp                       0x1047a70a4 CapturePipeline.setupVDO() + 4034 (CapturePipeline.swift:4034)
 3  MyApp                       0x10478c3f4 CapturePipeline.configureSession() + 1025 (CapturePipeline.swift:1025)
 4  MyApp                       0x1047bc5fc partial apply for closure #1 in CapturePipeline.setupSession() + 4338992636
 5  MyApp                       0x104721008 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4338356232 (<compiler-generated>:4338356232)
```

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift#L178: “Invoked by the compiler when the subexpression of a `try!` expression throws an error.”

Answer (score 4):

The initialisation of `AVCaptureDeviceInput` can throw, by using `try!` you're assuming that nothing will ever be thrown, which otherwise will crash your app.

Use a [do/catch](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html) to catch the error and get more information about it:

```
do {
    let audioIn = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)
} catch {
    debugPrint(error)
}
```

Comment: You could also do `if let audioIn = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice) {}` if one is not concerned about the error message